# can't find getByEmail() model function in ZF 1.12 app that is being used by other parts of code

Tags: php, mysql, apache, zend-framework

OK this may be a rookie question so please bear with me.

Web app using ZF 1.12 on a LAMP stack with Apache 2.4.9, PHP 5.4.30, MySQL 5.5.38

We have a **model->getByEmail($email)** function that is being called in a number of places:

- member password change
- send reset password link
- newsletter unsubscribe
- etc...

call example:

```
$this->model_member = new Model_Member () ;
$user = $this->model_member->getByEmail($input) ;
            if (empty($user)) {
...etc
```

***...but the getByEmail() function is not defined in the models/member.php (or any other) file ?***

---

The closest thing in can find to a getByEmail() function is called getById() which is located in models/Vc.php - the base model that models/member.php extends :

```
function getById($id, $field = 'id') {
    return $this->fetchRow ( $this->select ()->where ( "$field = ?", $id ) );
}
```

Obviously **getById()** would work too if the member table heading `email` was also input as `$field` along with `$email` as `$id` value - which it doesn't seem to be the case in any of the **getByEmail()** calls.

...in other words **getById()** does exactly what I would expect a **getByEmail()** should do, only **getByEmail()** would be tailored for $email only, whereas **getById()** can search for any type of id value...

---

I'm just stumped how there is a **getByEmail()** function that is being called, seems to work fine, but the function doesn't exist anywhere in the code (custom or otherwise)?

The only thing I can think of is that it that **model->getByEmail()** is somehow using the **getById()** function

- but how can a call to the **model->getByEmail()** redirect to a **model->getById()** ?

Is there a custom function I should be looking for that could replace "Email" with "Id" and add the $field string ?
...and why would it be coded that way ? Isn't it easier to just use the general **getById()** function and define the $field and $value everywhere ?

...or is there some basic features I'm misunderstanding of how php / ZF works ?

Again, I'm not getting errors when using the code that calls the **getByEmail()** function.

No related errors (ZF or otherwise) appearing in `sudo tail -f /etc/httpd/logs/error_log`

---

Code search using Aptana 3.0 :

- searched the entire workspace (Ctrl + H) for getByEmail - only shows view phtml files USING the function (nothing in the Zend library etc)
- searched also for resources (Ctrl + T) on the off chance it was a stand alone file (?)

I've done a google search for :

- Zend + getByEmail - and most come up with custom functions, doesn't seem to be a built in ZF function
- php + **getByEmail** - it doesn't appear to be a standard php function
- getByEmail - seems to reference only custom php code written and added manually to sites
- it's not appearing in any of the other libraries in the code I'm not sure what else to search for...

Comment: Sounds like it's being handled by a `__call()` magic method, either in the base class or something it extends. Can you give any more info about the base class?

Comment: @TimFountain I think you're on to something - found this in Vc.php

`public function __call($name, $value) {
 if (strpos ( $name, 'getAllBy' ) !== false) {
  $fieldName = str_replace ( 'getAllBy', '', $name );
  $field = Inflector::underscore ( $fieldName );
 return $this->fetchAll ( $this->select ()->where ( "$field = ?", $value )->order ( "id Desc" ) );
  } else if (strpos ( $name, 'getBy' ) !== false) {
  $fieldName = str_replace ( 'getBy', '', $name );
  $field = Inflector::underscore ( $fieldName );
   return $this->fetchRow ( $this->select ()->where ( "$field = ?", $value ) );
 }
}`